# What is the best way to work with big data in mysql? (Follow-up between members, notifications etc.)

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, security, bigdata

I have a blog site. I want my members to be able to follow the topics and each other.

```
Topics Table
id - title - content - tags - cat_id

Users Table
id - username - pass - nickname - mail - etc..
```

I have 2 different scenarios in mind.I could not find the best solution

**Scenario 1**

```
follows Table
id - user_id - topic_ids
1      1        1|2|3|4|5|...

notifications Table
id - user_ids - message
1    1|2|3|..   img_url|url|message..

notification_read Table
id - user_id - noti_id
1      1          1
```

In this scenario, notifications can be sent without too many columns. It feels like I get better performance as it takes up less space.

but this method sounds like it creates security holes. (use of longtext with no character limits (for topic_ids and user_ids))

**Scenario 2**

```
follows Table
id - user_id - topic_id
1      1        1
2      1        2
3      1        3
..     "       ..
..   same id   ..

notifications Table
id - user_id - read - msg_img - msg_url  -  msg
1       1       1     test.jpg   /test      New topic has been added in the category you follow.  
2       2       0     test.jpg   /test      New topic has been added in the category you follow.
3       3       0     test.jpg   /test      New topic has been added in the category you follow.
..     ..       ..    same img   same url   same msg
```

In this scenario, it creates 1 row for each follower.If 10000 people follow 1 category, it will create 10000 rows for 1 notification.

**Why is there a table of notification_read?**

I think too many people cannot edit on one column at the same time.For this reason, I wanted it to be a space where I could add those who read the notifications to different columns. (If I am wrong about this, please write.)

**Which scenario should I continue with?**

Actually, the logic I want to do is like facebook. Only people cannot add topics.

Topic follow-up (new comment written.)
Member follow-up (commented on a topic. Left a statement on a topic.)
Category tracking (A new video has been added to this category.)

and he needs to be able to see them in the flow.

There may be alternative ideas other than the 1st and 2nd scenario, I would be glad if you share.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the main `SELECTs`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is too long for a comment.  In SQL, you *never* want to store multiple id columns in a string.  Here are reasons why:

- Values should be stored using the appropriate type.  Numbers are not strings.
- Relationships between tables should use properly declared foreign key relationships.
- Columns in SQL are designed to contain a single value, not multiple values.
- SQL has poor string parsing functionality.
- Having to parse strings to get values prevents the optimizer from using indexes and partitions and other optimization strategies.
- SQL has a wonderful way to represent lists.  It is called a table.

In other words, your first scenario should not be even considered seriously as a data model.